# How to properly prevent a data race?

Tags: go

According to the [docs](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) doing the following prevents a data race:

```
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(5)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go func(j int) {
            fmt.Println(j) // Good. Read local copy of the loop counter.
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
```

however if I have code such as:

```
type Job struct {
    Work []string
}

var Queue chan Job


func work(id string, type int32) {
    
    job := Job{Work: []string{"A","B","C"}}
    
    go func(j Job, ty int32) {
        if ty == 1 {
        // do some other task
        }
        Queue <- j
    } (job, type) // RACE ON THIS LINE

    if type == 1 {
        // do something
    }

    return
}
```

*work* is being called via. gRPC.

the data race detector tells me that the go routine is producing a data race. I am thinking that there is something I am missing here but can't quite seem to find what that is.

Comment: Where does the race detector show you have a race? Please show a full example of what you're doing.

Comment: @JimB I have added a comment in the code to identify where the detector says there is a race - really what I am trying to get to the bottom of is why in one scenario of passing the values through the goroutine works and in another scenario it does not.

Comment: A race requires 2 or more points in the code, where is the competing write?

Comment: @JimB you sparked me to look in another place, it seems like rather than a call to the routine itself it was a call to a counter in a function in "do some other task" which is missing a locking mechanism - thank you for your replies!